# Locust: request_success.fire does not do anything

Tags: locust

I made a wrapper for a Poly API function. The wrapper is supposed to fire some Locust events.  An API function "authorize" is called successfully (if wrong parameters are supplied to "authorize" then it throws an exception in the console). It looks though that Locust event function is not. The statistics is not reflected in the Locust interface, like nothing is happening.

```python
import time
from business_logic_refactored import BusinessLogic
from locust import User, task, between, events
class PolyClinet(BusinessLogic):

_locust_environment = None

def __getattr__(self, name):
    #func = BusinessLogic.__getattr__(self, name)
    func = BusinessLogic.authorize
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            events.request_success.fire(request_type="TEST", name=name, response_time=total_time, response_length=0)
            self._locust_environment.events.request_success.fire(request_type="TEST", name=name, response_time=total_time, response_length=0)
        except Fault as e:
            total_time = int((time.time() - start_time) * 1000)
            self._locust_environment.events.request_failure.fire(request_type="TEST", name=name, response_time=total_time, exception=e)
        else:
            total_time = int((time.time() - start_time) * 1000)
            events.request_success.fire(request_type="grpc", name=name, response_time=total_time, response_length=0)
            ###self._locust_environment.events.request_success.fire(request_type="TEST", name=name, response_time=total_time, response_length=0)
            # In this example, I've hardcoded response_length=0. If we would want the response length to be
            # reported correctly in the statistics, we would probably need to hook in at a lower level

    return wrapper

class PolyUser(User):
    abstract = True
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PolyUser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.client = PolyClient()
        self.client._locust_environment = self.environment

class ApiUser(PolyUser):
    @task(10)
    def get_time(self):
        self.client.authorize("user", "password","URL")
```

UPD 06/11/20:

Basically, the problem is that .**getattr** is only called on a non-existing function. Here is the script to try and see the difference/problem:

```python
class BusinessLogic():
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return name
    def authorize(self):
        print("authorize")

class PolyClinet(BusinessLogic):

    _locust_environment = None

def __getattr__(self, name):
    print("getattr")
    func = BusinessLogic.__getattr__(self, name)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("wrapper")
        func()
    return wrapper

class PolyUser():
    abstract = True
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PolyUser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.client = PolyClinet()
        #self.client._locust_environment = self.environment
class ApiUser(PolyUser):
    def get_time(self):
        print("get_time")
        self.client.authorize()
    def get_time2(self):
        print("get_time2")
        self.client.authorize2()
c= ApiUser()
c.get_time()
print("*******")
c.get_time2()
```

Answer (score 0):

To log an event, you’re supposed to do                 self.environment.events.request_success.fire(...) in your User class

See https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/2958d265857a8730af3b6cd9fd05f8839ec8f383/locust_plugins/users.py#L70 for example.

I’m not sure what happens when you call events.request_success directly. Maybe it should throw an exception.. It could probably be a lot better documented as well...

Edit: The root problem was that BusinessLogic has its own regular (non-getattr) methods, in which case, subclassing it will make a client unable to wrap the BusinessLogic method (because the client's getattr will not get called) The example in the documentation should be improved. https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1423

Comment: Sorry for not providing the full code block right away. I think I followed the example here: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html.  Do you suggest moving self.environment.events.request_success.fire(...) somewhere else?

Comment: Hmm, no now it looks good. Maybe remove the "bare" events.request_success.fire calls though. Can you throw some print statements in there (before and after the self._locust_environment.events.request_xxx.fire) to make sure the code is actually being run?

Comment: I also highly recommend trying it in a debugger: https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/debug_ex.py

Comment: Ok, so basically the problem is the following:

In the example provided at docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html it assumes that an API function call goes through one function, so the __getattr__ is invoked when every time an undefined function is called, then __getattr__ passes the call further.

In my case there are 40 functions defined in the class which I am trying to wrap, the functions are known and exist, so the __getattr__ is not invoked. So, I guess I need to either wrap each of 40 functions individually OR figure out how to make a universal wrapper for 40 functions.

Comment: Hmm... I dont get it. Why does func = BusinessLogic.__getattr__(self, name) not work for you?

Comment: Well, BusinessLogic.__getattr__(self, name)  would work if it was called.  In my example I have BusinessLogic with 40 functions including authorize. In the locust documentation example there is ServerProxy with basically no functions defined.  A function call ServerProxy.xyz triggers .__getattr__ which in turn passes the call over to the XML-RPC server. A function call BusinessLogic.authorize does not trigger .__getattr__ because authorize is defined by the BusinessLogic, so the call goes straight to authorize.  So, the wrapper example as it is does not work for my case.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are not making sense. You should explicitly call BusinessLogic.__getattr__(self, name). Just uncomment that line in your locustfile. Then it does not matter whether BusinessLogic's functions are explicitly defined or not.

Comment: I have added an example to make it clear. Please, see above.

Comment: Thanks for your example! The code crashes for me, because this code:
def __getattr__(self, name):
        return name
should return a function, not a string

Comment: Ah, but I think I see your problem: PolyClinet should not be a subclass of BusinessLogic

Comment: Just make it a true wrapper that instantiates its own BusinessLogic object in its constructor and it should work fine. I will file a ticket to fix the documentation to be more clear.

Comment: Super! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the Locust version. In version 1.4.4 `events.request_success.fire` works (and named `EventHook`) but in version 1.5.1 it should be just `request` object and `events.request_success.fire` has already DeprecatedEventHook name.
https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.request